# Custom exceptions with properties - how to ensure property is not null while conforming to CA rules?

Tags: c#, .net

The reason for creating a custom exception class is - at least for me - that I need to transport additional information, e.g. some domain object.
To achieve this, I add a read-only property to my exception class and provide a constructor that initializes this property and allows only non-null values.

Now, according to [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx) and [Code Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182151.aspx), every Exception type should have at least four specific constructors.

The end-result is that it is possible to create instances of my custom exception class that don't have my custom property set.

There are two problems with this:

1. Every exception handler would have to check if that property is `null`
2. Some exception handlers wouldn't be able to do anything useful without that additional property.

How to solve this dilemma?

Comment: @user1416420: Most of the guidelines exist for good reasons. Because someone else ignores them doesn't mean I should too. Having said this, I *do* ignore guidelines if I think they are not applicable to my scenario. Still, I am trying to find solutions that are sensible *and* conform to the guidelines. And that's the point of this question.

Comment: The reason why the guidelines are not conformed to in a lot of BCL code is simple: It's legacy code, a lot of which has been written by C++ developers before the guidelines existed.

Comment: @user1416420: Yeah, but that really isn't the point of this question, ok? I don't care who does or does not follow those guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you supply a default value for your domain object, a Null Object perhaps? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) That way, none of your exception handlers will need to be the wiser. Have the Null Object instance of your domain object do exactly nothing when any of its methods or properties are used.

Another alternative is to use [SuppressMessage] to avoid the code analysis message and then not have a constructor with zero parameters. The problem then becomes that your class is no longer serializable. This may or may not be a problem for you.

Finally, consider creating an intermediary class, call it DomainObjectExceptionHandler. It is responsible for handling the exception should one occur:

```
 public abstract class DomainObjectExceptionHandlerBase {
     public abstract void HandleException();
 }
```

Then have an implementation that knows what to do when an exception has occurred with a real domain object:

```
 public class DomainObjectExceptionHandler : DomainObjectExceptionHandlerBase {
     private DomainObject domainObject;
     public DomainObjectExceptionHandler(DomainObject domainObject) {
         this.domainObject = domainObject;
     public override void HandleException() { 
         // do real recovery work with the domain object
     }
 }
```

And then a null object that does nothing:

```
public class NullDomainObjectExceptionHandler : DomainObjectExceptionHandlerBase {
    public override void HandleException() { 
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Now your exception class can have the four recommended signatures, including:

```
public class DomainObjectException {
    public DomainObjectException() {
        this.Handler = new NullDomainObjectExceptionHandler();
    }

    public DomainObjectException(DomainObject domainObject) {
        this.Handler = new DomainObjectExceptionHandler(domainObject);
    }

    public DomainObjectExceptionHandlerBase Handler { get; private set; }
}
```

Your throwing code looks like this:

```
if (domainObject.IsUnhappy())
    throw new DomainObjectException(domainObject);
```

And your exception handlers look like this:

```
try {
    FrobulateDomainObjects();
} catch (DomainObjectException ex) {
    ex.Handler.HandleException();
}
```

Note how the exception handler doesn't need to know about the presence of a DomainObject, it delegates that to the DomainObjectExceptionHandler.

Comment: Good idea with the Null object. That would solve issue #1. However, issue #2 isn't solved with this. `SuppressMessage` isn't really an option, because the conditions for suppressing this rule haven't been met. I know that I can still suppress it and maybe even will, but the point of this question is to find a solution while conforming to "the rules".

Comment: Can you perhaps be more specific on what the event handlers are trying to do with the exception? I still think that with a properly implemented null object, your exception handler should just be able to call a "HandleException" method on the null object and not worry about the specifics.

Comment: One example would be the following: Consider a method that takes an `Invoice` object to book it. My exception will be thrown if that invoice already has been booked. The exception handler in this scenario will perform some operations on the already booked invoice to fix its status. For this operation I naturally need the invoice object.

Comment: How about when you throw your exception you don't pass an Invoice explicitly, but a InvoiceStatusFixer object. The InvoiceStatusFixer takes an Invoice as its constructor parameter. Then, have a NullInvoiceStatusFixer that does nothing. Now, you have one exception class with an InvoiceStatusFixer property. If you create exception instances with the parameterless constructor, create a NullInvoiceStatusFixer and assign it to the property. Then have your exception handlers call methods on the InvoiceStatusFixer; they will be unaware of whether a real invoice is involved or not.

Comment: That's it. I am not sure it is applicable in every possible scenario, but that surely is a good alternative that keeps existing functionality while conforming to "the rules". It would be great, if you could add this to your actual answer.